# Am I allowed to marry while travelling to Bulgaria on a tourist visa

Tags: marriage, bulgaria, egyptian-citizens, bulgarian-citizens

I am a citizen of Egypt. Would I be allowed to get married in Bulgaria while visiting Bulgaria on a tourist visa? If it matters, my fiancée is Bulgarian.

what will be easier to marry her in Egypt or in Bulgaria?

Comment: get married in whichever country you would like to settle down.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier in Bulgaria because the level of bureaucracy in Egypt is likely to be higher. It would also be easier to have your marriage recognized for the purposes of moving to Bulgaria.